# How to create parameters in dialogflow using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to create a parameter in node js that stays in the same intent for a life spam of 2.
It should ask for the first value then validates it, then second value and so on

[image]

what I have done

```
function test(agent) {
      var first = agent.parameters.first;
      var second = agent.parameters.second;
      
      agent.context.set({
        name: 'test',
        lifespan: 2,
        parameters: {
          'first': first,
          'second': second
        },
      });
     agent.add("first parameter then second parameter");
}
```

Should I create the parameters in dialogflow as follows and implement it in node js or it should be done all in node js. If so how can I do it?

[image]

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in general the best option is to set all the intent's parameters via Dialogflow and then interact via Node.js client library.
Actually it would be also possible to do everything with Node.js, but in case you are using (or may use in the future) one of the [integration options](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations) using [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview) to manage agent’s responses you should set a [webhook service](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook) and manage responses via [API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/common-types#webhookrequest_references).
Therefore, I think setting the parameters in Dialogflow before interacting with Node.js would be the simplest and straightforward approach for any use case.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I found out that the issue was related to the session id being changed with every request by overriding each other

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, incase anyone facing the same issue, the request being sent must have the same session id to avoid overriding the values.